I'm trying to run an audio player in python under rpi5. I need to run in sudo mode in order to access GPIO. I can't seem to find an app to do this
Playing audio file from python while python is in sudo mode.  I've tried VLC and it won't let me run in sudo mode.  I've tried PyAudio.  It does nothing under sudo mode (it's hard to weed out the real error messages.  python 3.11.2 Raspberry Pi 2024-07-04,  Real VNC 7.12.0 (r14) x64.
VLC under sudo mode - bluetooth sound
PyAudio under sudo mode - bluetooth sound - not under sudo mode works fine

You might be better asking the question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/
